# Change colour of an item view in recycler view after comparison with its textview data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with 'n' number of ItemViews in it. These ItemViews contain Textviews with data with are updated through Firestore.

Now I need to compare one of the value0(getexpirydate) in the Textviews with another value1(Current date). Then if value1 > value0, then change the colour of that specific Itemview to RED. else GREEN.

```
ContractsAdapter


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class ContractsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContractsAdapter.ContractViewHolder>{

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Contracts> contractsList;


    private FirebaseFirestore db;



    public ContractsAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Contracts> contractsList){
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.contractsList = contractsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContractsAdapter.ContractViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        return new ContractViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.contract_layout, parent, false)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContractsAdapter.ContractViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Contracts contract = contractsList.get(position);

        holder.contractname.setText(contract.getStationorpackagename());
        holder.contractorname.setText(contract.getContractorname());
        holder.dateofcommencement.setText(contract.getDateofcommnew());
        holder.dateofexpiry.setText(contract.getDateofexpiry());
        holder.licensefee.setText(contract.getLicensefees());
        holder.contracttenure.setText(contract.getContracttenure());
        holder.datesixmonths.setText(contract.getDateexpirysixmonths());
        holder.dateoffloating.setText(contract.getDateofnewfloatingtender());
        holder.dateofopening.setText(contract.getDateofopeningtender());
        holder.dateofaward.setText(contract.getDateofletterofawardee());
        holder.dateofcommnew.setText(contract.getDateofcommencementofnew());
        holder.reasonsfordelay.setText(contract.getReasonsfordelay());
        holder.duedatelicensefee.setText(contract.getDuedatelicensefee());

        /*int po = 2;
        if(po == position){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }*/

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return contractsList.size(); }

    class ContractViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView contractname, contractorname, dateofcommencement, dateofexpiry, licensefee, contracttenure, datesixmonths;
        TextView dateoffloating, dateofopening, dateofaward, dateofcommnew, reasonsfordelay;

        TextView textviewtenure, sixmonths, floatingtext, opening, award, commnew, duedatelicensefee;

        public ContractViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            contractname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contract_name);
            contractorname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contractor_name);
            dateofcommencement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_of_commencement);
            dateofexpiry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_of_expiry);
            licensefee = itemView.findViewById(R.id.license_fee);
            contracttenure = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contract_tenure);
            datesixmonths = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_six_months);
            dateoffloating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_floating_new);
            dateofopening = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_of_opening);
            dateofaward = itemView.findViewById(R.id.letter_of_award);
            dateofcommnew = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_of_commnew);
            reasonsfordelay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reasons_delay);
            duedatelicensefee = itemView.findViewById(R.id.due_license_fee);

            /// Text View for explanations
           textviewtenure = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
           sixmonths = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
           floatingtext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView16);
           opening = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView18);
           award = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView20);
           commnew = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
           //// End


            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCtx);
            builder.setTitle("Choose an action");

            final String[] action = {"Update/Modify Contract", "Delete Contract"};
            builder.setItems(action, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (action[which].equals("Update/Modify Contract")) {
                        Contracts contract = contractsList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, Update.class);
                        intent.putExtra("contract", contract);
                        mCtx.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    else if (action[which].equals("Delete Contract")){
                        Contracts contract = contractsList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, Delete.class);
                        intent.putExtra("contract", contract);
                        mCtx.startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }
            });

// create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

So was able to make it work by adding this before setText.

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    try {
        Date date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(date);
        Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(contract.getDateofexpiry());
        if (d1.after(date1)){
            holder.contractname.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? Comparing date? or change color of textview?

Comment: First Compare the date in the Textview. Then if it satisfies the condition change colour of that specific Itemview.

Comment: You can place the `condition` in the `onBindViewHolder()` before `setText()` and set the `textColor` to the `RED`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContractsAdapter.ContractViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Contracts contract = contractsList.get(position);

    if (contract.getCurrentDate() > contract.getDateofexpiry()) {
        holder.dateofexpiry.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    holder.dateofexpiry.setText(contract.getDateofexpiry());
}
```

Comment: Thanks was able to make it work with this.

String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        try {
            Date date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(date);
            Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(contract.getDateofexpiry());
            if (d1.after(date1)){
                holder.contractname.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: I am glad it worked. BTW, welcome to the SO community.

Comment: Let me know, if you need any further guidance.